# Display error using pstool and psfragfig

Tags: eps, epstopdf, pstool

I want to include a sketch drawn in TpX in LaTeX using `psfragfig`.

Unfortunately the sketch doesn't look like as desired when included with `psfragfig`. Only parts of the sketch are displayed - some lines are missing.

Using `\includegraphics` without `.eps` file ending the sketch is displayed as erroneous as with `psfragfig`.

Only by using `\includegraphics` and explicitly defining the `.eps` file ending the sketch lines shows up correctly.

I wrote this MWE (download link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3ons5204gf07tgk/AAA67uPk9G3YLAwd4hyFETMla?dl=0):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[process=all]{pstool}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{psfrag}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{fig/StraightLug.eps}
    \caption{includegraphics: fig/StraightLug.eps}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{fig/StraightLug}
    \caption{includegraphics: fig/StraightLug}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \psfragfig[width=0.5\linewidth]{fig/StraightLug}{
        \psfrag{W=2R}[bc]{$W = 2R$}%
        \psfrag{d}{$d$}%
        \psfrag{R}{$R_a$}%
    }%
    \caption{psfragfig: fig/StraightLug}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output looks like that:

[image: Output of MWE above]

There seems to be an error during converting the EPS file to PDF. Does anyone had this problem before? I highly appreciate any suggestions to solve this issue.

I use TeX Live 2019 and updated Ghostscript (v9.50).

Comment: Anyone any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please upload the files again, especially the EPS?

Comment: Sure, i updated the link above...

Comment: Can you check the log file to see which images are actually used? There should be some lines saying `[filename]  used on input line XX`. It is possible that there are other files with the same name (but with different extensions) that can explain the difference between your Figure 1 and Figure 2. The log file also gives some information about the epstopdf process that might help to identify the issue. Also check the contents of the folder in Windows Explorer/Finder (Mac)/Nautilus (Linux) and open the images in a graphics program to see what is happening.